# How can I configure syntax highlighting for a custom language in vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

We use our own little language for small tasks, but we do not have Vim highlighting support for it.

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own syntax file and put it in `~/.vim/syntax/*.vim`.

[`:help syntax`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) is a good start. Take a look at the existing syntax files in `/usr/share/vim` too.