# Extend vim's syntax highlighting for only *some* files?

Tags: vim, xml, syntax-highlighting

Our software has many .xml configuration files.  Vim colors these files, using e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/xml.vim`.  But can we customize the coloring for *just* these files, and not for *all* .xml files?

(An example of such customizing would be coloring the text between `<schmoo>` and `</schmoo>` tags.  But this question isn't about *how* to color, nor is it about XML.  I hope for an answer that applies equally well to Python or YAML or hundreds of other formats.)

Can another file in the .xml files' directory override or extend `syntax/xml.vim`?  (Unlikely:  [runtimepath](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'runtimepath') doesn't mention the current directory; neither do `autochdir` or `getcwd()` seem to help.)

What about something in an environment variable, or in an .xml file itself (at the top or bottom; or inline like jsbegin/jsend in [Vim custom syntax highlighting, include other language syntax in a specified range](https://superuser.com/questions/369994/vim-custom-syntax-highlighting-include-other-language-syntax-in-a-specified-ran))?

Or must the extensions go into each user's `~/.vim/after/syntax/xml.vim` (which is used for *all* .xml files)?  That would be suboptimal, but tolerable for extensions specialized enough to not collide with other things (like "schmoo" above).

Related: [How can I configure syntax highlighting for a custom language in vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/213096/how-can-i-configure-syntax-highlighting-for-a-custom-language-in-vim)

Reference: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that vim's `modeline` is on.  `:set modeline?` should respond `modeline` instead of `nomodeline`.  If necessary, set it in your vimrc.  (Security concerns are pretty much obsolete by now.)

In a particular .xml file, include this line: `// vim: filetype=xmlWithSchmoos` (If not xml, replace `//` with whatever starts a comment in that language.)

Create `~/.vim/syntax/xmlWithSchmoos.vim` or `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/xmlWithSchmoos.vim`, containing the single line `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/xml.vim`.

Append stanzas to `xmlWithSchmoos.vim`.  For example, for red `schmoo` tags and what's between them, append:

```
:syntax region xyzzy start=/<schmoo>/ end=/<\/schmoo>/
:highlight xyzzy ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

Of course, rename to something meaningful the placeholders `schmoo`, `xml`, `xmlWithSchmoos`, and `xyzzy`.